# What are cp_tal stored procedures?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a database for my web project and there are a lot of `cp_tal_NAME` stored procedures in it which I did not create. These appear to be generated SP's with the name format `cp_tal_SomeTableName_` and one of the following suffixes; `del`, `get`, `ins`, `upd`.

My project uses entity framework. Are these some feature created by that?

Comment: Was the database created by you, or did you inherit it with a project?

Comment: Those stored procs are definitely **not** generated by EF - those must be something custom made - those names sound like a generated data access layer of some sort, but that's definitely nothing "official" or publicly known, I think....

Answer (score 0):

"cp_tal" stored procedures are not created by EF.